# simple xml to dictionary converter for android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I knew there is xmlpull parser for parsing xml on android platform.
is there any Generic custom xml parser for android something similar like mentioned in the below link.

**http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/**

Comment: An Android developer may not be Iphone developer..please ask what do you want...

Comment: True but I have stated work on Android os just know.... thought if something similar available for Andorid.